# MySQL simple/double quotation syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Please apologize for the basicness of my question, but this is driving me crazy for more than an hour now. I would like to modify the here below sql statement by using simple quotation marks instead of the double once. I tried and tried but I do not manage to find the solution. Thank you very much in advance for the replies. Cheers. Marc.

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query("

SELECT * 
FROM sorties 
WHERE srt_date_sortie BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'

");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, since your question isn't very clear, and you don't give any expectations (like what you tried and how you expected that to work, versus how it actually worked).

In the absence of content, I'll take a stab at what I think you want.

```
$result = mysql_query('

    SELECT * 
    FROM sorties 
    WHERE srt_date_sortie BETWEEN \'' . $date . ' 00:00:00\' AND \'' . $date . ' 23:59:59\'

');
```

Comment: Hello rockfest. Thanks for the help. The think is, I need to incorporate that code into a bigger and more complex sql statement that starts with single quotations. That is why I need to find a way to transform my statement.

Comment: So this is precisely what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change your query in

```
SELECT * 
FROM sorties
WHERE DATE(srt_date_sortie) = $date
```

Comment: @Thorsten: I think OP can use double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the query without inserting other ones in the middle. Am I missing something? :)

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the lack of detailed explanations. I need to use the BETWEEN statment as $date as "Y-m-d" as format whereas in my db the date format is "Y-m-d H:i". So the DATE(srt_date_sortie) is not for me in that particular case...

Comment: No, I think it is fine, just gave it a try. Thought you needed to quote dates in SQL stings.

Comment: @Thorsten: I cannot try it now, but I'm pretty sure you can use YYYY-MM-DD format without quotes...

Comment: I just tried it out. It is not working. Thank you anyway Marco.

Answer (score 1):

1. I tend to find date comparisons problematic so I use the TO_DAYS function to change them into integers which removes any formatting issues and also issues of comparing dates to date-time fields
2. Also use double quotes for MySQL queries since MySQL uses a single quote as a string qualifier
3. While PHP can concatenate string variables within a literal, I prefer to show the concatenation for readability
4. The $date variable needs a single quote around it to mark it as a date string

Final Query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM sorties 
WHERE TO_DAYS(srt_date_sortie) = TO_DAYS('".$date."')");
```